# Считывание стрелок на С#

Tags: c#, консоль

Как мне считывать нажатия клавиш на С#? Я пробовал метод Console.ReadKey(), но получается, если нажать 2 раза. А проверка с Enter работает с первого раза. Вот код:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Вверх");
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Вниз");
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Вправо");
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Влево");
        }
    }
}
```

P.s. я смотрел как использовать Console.ReadKey() с официального ссайта Microsoft (корпорации-создателя C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы дважды выполняете `Console.ReadKey()` за одну итерацию цикла, поэтому и нажатия требуется два, а не одно.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleKey key;
    while ((key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key) != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("Вверх");
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("Вниз");
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("Вправо");
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("Влево");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: тоесть оно думает, что я должен нажать сперва за Enter, а потом за стрелку?

Comment: @TheOxlice не понял, сначала считывается кнопка, любая, а потом по порядку проверяется, с какая же она была. А в вашем коде - да, так и есть.

Answer (score 0):

Вы так одно нажатие на проверку `Enter`. Попробуйте так:

```cs
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                break;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Вверх");
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Вниз");
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Вправо");
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)    Console.WriteLine("Влево");
        }
```

Но ещё лучше, конечно, через `switch` проверять, как в другом ответе.

Answer (score 0):

не совсем ясна задача, что вы решаете, но попробуйте так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {

        ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
        ConsoleKey key = info.Key;
        string msg = String.Empty;
        switch (key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                msg = "Вверх";
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                msg = "Вниз";
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                msg = "Вправо";
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                msg = "Влево";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что делает строка "if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))" и "String.Empty"? Объясните пожалуйста!

Comment: @TheOxlice почитайте про [IsNullOrEmpty](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) на оф. сайте, а так же про [оператор логического отрицания](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-). А `string.Empty` - название говорит само за себя. Это просто пустая строка, которая не содержит ни одного символа

Comment: @Aarnihauta тоесть это необязательно использовать?

Comment: нет, не обязательно. просто пример вывода сообщения в консоль при определённых условиях

Comment: @TheOxlice да, данное условие не обязательно